# Consume full record from ReferenceInput then fire an API call and show the result

Tags: react-admin

After some research I am still wondering what's the recommended way to handle this.
In a "Create a new order" form in react-admin I want to preview and refresh the price and some other informations **before** submitting.

To be more precise I have a basic form with some ReferenceInput for customer, product, applied coupons and it would be great if a change in those three inputs occur that the shown price was recalculated server side then shown.

Part of the solution may be in this blog post : https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/08/27/react-admin-tutorials-custom-forms-related-records.html but I am still unsure as how to do it the clean way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where  is your code? What have you tried so far?